# passive - present perfect vs passive - simple present

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, present-tense

> Life is beginning to look up a bit- the heavy **rain has stopped** .
>
> **The rain has stopped** and people are walking away
>
> After **the rain is stopped** slowly His father leads him to the village
>
> The librarian says you have to go home now,**the rain is stopped.**

Need explanation on when to use passive - present perfect and passive - simple present.

what is the meaning of below sentences:

> train has stopped
>
> train is stopped

Give me one example using above two sentences.

Comment: I don't think *the rain is stopped* is correct (or at least it sounds odd) in 3 & 4. Also in 3 *slowly* in not correctly used (, slowly his??). What is the source of these examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of *stopped* as the complement of *BE* might imply either of two readings:

- A passive sense, in which *the rain* is the Patient of the verb *stop* and would act as its direct object in an active sentence: “Something stopped the rain.” That does not appear to be the case here, and it is not a way in which we ordinarily speak of *rain*. Rather, *rain* is commonly treated as the Agent of its activity: “The rain started” (not “The rain was started” ), “The rain kept falling” or “The rain it raineth every day”.
- A ‘deverbal’ sense, in which *stopped* is felt to act entirely as an adjective, with no feeling of verbness. *Stopped* does play this role occasionally—we might say that “A train was stopped on the siding”—but even there it is more usual to say that that the train *had* stopped.

This is not to say that *rain is stopped* is either unknown or incorrect. It does occur—you can find instances on Google—but most of these derive from non-native speakers or from works of fiction which exhibit an aspiration to literariness which they fail to achieve.

I would avoid this use, and stick with the perfects.